# Mongoose Many to many relationship with addition field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi guys Im trying to create a quiz App, currently I have 2 models:

**Quiz model**: (which stores all questions, like a category for questions)

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const QuizSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type:String, required:true },
  slug: { type:String, required:true },
});
```

**Question Model**: (which store a single question, with answers etc)

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  question: { type:String, required:true },
  options: [String],
  answers: Array,
  quizCategory: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // here is relate each question to Quiz
    ref: "Quiz",
  }]
});
```

So the Problem Im having is this one. I would like to store Question in Quiz Category for that I have added this code:

```
quizCategory: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // here is relate each question to Quiz
    ref: "Quiz",
  }]
```

For relation, and would allow me to store 1 Question in many Quiz categories, that code above is allowing me that.

But know when I store same Question in different Quiz(categories) I would like to have its position also saved, So for example:

I have 4 Questions: q1,q2,q3,q4 and 2 Quiz categories: 'Cat 1', 'Cat2'...

I would like to save q1 in 'Cat 1' with position 2, and also save that same question in 'Cat 2' with position 5.

And then q2 save in 'Cat 1' on position 4 only, something like this

**I would like for each collection of questions I store in Quiz category have order, etc its position. But to be able to reuse 1 Question on few categories with different position, if Im clear** :)

Comment: Your model and the questions you are asking doesn't make sense. If you want the questions for a category in a particular order, you should be storing the question ids within the categories collection.

Comment: @prasad_ yes the model is probably wrong but how could I change it to support that ?